# Node.js how to pass variable reference so it's in callback functions scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I'm trying to create a node.js app using the leaflet library, however the WMS I'm using uses Basic Authentication which isn't supported in leaflet so I've extended Tilelayer.WMS to grab the image with a seperate request and convert it to base64. This is all working correctly however I'm fairly new to node/javascript in general and have no idea how I'm supposed to pass a reference to my tile variable through so it's available in the later callback.

```
readerLoaded(reader) {    
    console.log(reader.target.result);

    //want to be able to do something like this in here
    tile.src = reader.target.result;
},

createTile (coords, done) {
    var tile = document.createElement('img');

    //Removed non-relevant code setting up header options etc                                           
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = this.readerLoaded;

    http.get(url, options).subscribe(
        m => {reader.readAsDataURL(m.blob());}, 
        error => {console.log(error);}
    );

    return tile;
}
```

How do I pass a reference to the specific tile created in each createTile call so it's available in the subsequent readerLoaded call?

Also is there an efficient way to delay createTile returning until the readerLoaded callback has finished? I know if I was designing this myself it'd be a callback which was executed when it was ready however since I'm editing an existing library rewriting large parts of it seems like more effort than it's worth.

Thanks.

Comment: `reader.onload = () => { do something with tile };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you can't take an existing function definition like you show for `readerLoaded()` and "add" something to it's scope from within `createTile()`.  That's just not how scope works in Javascript.

The usual way to make variables available within a function are to pass them as arguments or define them in the existing parent scope.  Here's an example of passing as an argument.

```
readerLoaded(reader, tile) {    
    console.log(reader.target.result);

    //want to be able to do something like this in here
    tile.src = reader.target.result;
},

createTile (coords, done) {
    var tile = document.createElement('img');

    //Removed non-relevant code setting up header options etc                                           

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (reader) => {
        return this.readerLoaded(reader, tile);
    }

    http.get(url, options).subscribe(m =>{reader.readAsDataURL(m.blob());}, 
                                     error=>{console.log(error);});

    return tile;
}
```

If readerLoaded is going to be a method on an object, then you can't really define a temporaral variable such as `tile` in it's parent scope as there is no real Javascript syntax to do that.  So, it appears your best option here is to pass it as an argument.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Seems I was thinking about it all wrong, all I really needed was something like reader.onload = (loadedReader) => {tile.src = loadedReader.target['result']; }; Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user1671538 - Yep, that will work.  I assumed that `readerLoaded()` had a lot more code in it and need to be a method on an object, but if all it does is that one line of code, then yep that's the simplest way.